# How to say Fourier series of continuous function is continuous or not?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I had found Fourier series of $f(x)=\cos(\frac{x}{2}) , -\pi<x<\pi.$

Its Fourier series is given by 
$\displaystyle S(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{(-1)^n}{n+0.5}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n-0.5}\right]\cos(nx)$.

I am interested to know that is Fourier series is continuous or not.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If the continuous functions of the Fourier series converge *uniformly*, then the function to which the series converges will be continuous. This is a sufficient condition, but I don't know if it's necessary.

Comment: Incidentally, you can simplify the expression inside the square braces to $\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2-1/4}.$

Comment: $f(x) = \cos(x/2)$ for $? < x < ?$

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir .THat means series converges uniformly to continous function

Comment: @GCab Sir  for $-\pi<x<\pi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Adrian Keister pointed out in a comment, we have

$$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2-1/4}\cos(nx).$$

In absolute value the summands are bounded above by $1/(n^2-1/4).$ Because $\sum 1/(n^2-1/4)<\infty,$ Weierstrass M tells us the series converges uniformly on $[-\pi,\pi].$ Since each summand is continuous, so is $S(x).$

Comment: Dear Sir How to graph S(x) ? Can you please tell me?

Comment: If two continuous functions have the same Fourier coefficients, then they are identical. Here we see $\cos(x/2),S(x),$ both continuous, have the same Fourier coefficients. Therefore $S(x) = \cos(x/2).$